# How to insert data in CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, python-requests, export-to-csv

I have a problem with my Python script.

Basically what my script does is first it does a GET request to our API and extracts all ID's from the endpoint and then saves it in a CSV file.

Atm im having problems inserting data in the csv file. What i want is for my csv file to look like this after inserting data in:

```
id
1
2
3
...
```

Basically I want every id in their own row.

But what ends up being inserted is this:

```
id
1,2,3,...
```

I have tried `for` looping and few other things and nothing seemed to work out. I would love if anyone can help me with this problem. It's probably something really simple I just missed out.

My script code:

```py
import requests
import json
import csv
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath, parse

url = 'url'

headers = {
       "Authorization": "Bearer token"
    }

response = requests.get(url_v1, headers=headers)

JsonResponse = response.json()
converted = json.dumps(JsonResponse)

Data = json.loads(converted)
ParseData = parse('$..id')
Id = ParseData.find(Data)


open_file = open('C:/File/test.csv','w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(open_file)

list_id = []
fields = ['id']

for i in range(0, len(Id)):
    result = Id[i].value
    list_id.append(result)

writer.writerow(fields)

writer.writerow(list_id)


open_file.close()
```

Comment: `list_id.append([result])` and `writer.writerows(list_id)`

Comment: or `writerow` instead of append, since you go through them anyways

Comment: Both worked ty so much for your help.